# Justify that $k(a,b) = (ka,kb)$.

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to show that the map $T$ defined by $T(x,y)=(x-y,2x+3y)$ is a matrix transformation by showing that it has the additive property $T((a,b)+(c,d))=T(a,b)+T(c,d)$ and the homogeneity property $T(k(a,b))=kT(a,b)$, for any $(a,b), (c,d) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ and any $k \in \mathbb{R}$.

It's the homogeneity part that is causing me trouble. In my mind, I am trying to approach this without thinking of $(a,b)$ as a matrix/vector since I am showing that the function is a matrix transformation. But I don't recall ever multiplying an ordered pair by a number before!

My brain is telling me that $k(a,b)=(ka,kb)$ isn't a real thing unless $(a,b)$ is considered a vector.

Hopefully, I am making some sense. Can anyone help clarify this for me?

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: So is the domain of $T$ pairs of numbers, or 2-D vectors? It's a good distinction to be aware of, but does it matter for this problem? Given the answer, you might need to think about what every notation involved actually means.

Comment: Yes, I think that is part of my problem. The function is from R^2 to R^2 and it's given as taking in ordered pairs. If I want to stay in the realm of ordered pairs, can I say that k(a,b)=(ka,kb) ; does that have any meaning outside of vector space?

Comment: Geometrically, when you multiply a vector $(a,b)$ by a scalar $k$, you are changing the size and/or the direction of $(a,b)$. For example, multiplying the vector $(1,2)$ by $3$ gives the vector $(3,6)$. Note that this vector has the same direction of $(1,2)$, except is longer than it. On the other hand, if you multiply the $(1,2)$ by $-1$, you get $(-1,-2)$. In this case, the size did not change, but the vector that we obtain is “pointing” in the opposite direction.

Comment: Shortly, think of $(a,b)$ as a vector.

Comment: Would you have the same trouble with the addition $(a,b) + (c,d)$?

Comment: @peterwhy you know, that is so true! But for some reason that one didn't make my brain bend! So I am thinking that Air Mike is right, just think of it as a vector. And we can do this because there is no reason you can't do that. R^2 is R^2 no matter how you choose to represent its elements.

Comment: So if the domain is $\mathbb{R}^2$, we really have $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ and $T((x,y)) = (x-y, 2x+3y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$. We just often abbreviate $T((x,y))$ to $T(x,y)$. Does that help understand $T(k(a,b))$?

Comment: ... though that's when we think of $T$ as a function. If instead we approach from the idea of multiplying a matrix with a vector, we might have $v \in \mathbb{R}^2$ and write just $Tv$ for the product. In that case $T(a,b)$ is really a multiplication where $(a,b)$ is a vector.

Comment: @aschepler - Hmm, my answer is basically your comments. But I don't have your observation about $Tv$ notation. Do you mind if I include it? It seems useful.

Comment: @JonathanZ Sure

Answer (score 1):

Briefly, yes, $(x,y)$ is a vector, and you should treat it as such.

To get more detailed, there is an actual, technical difference between a function taking two real variables, which is written

$$f(x,y)$$

and a function taking a single argument that is a vector in $\mathbb R^2$. Since we write vectors with the notation $(x,y)$, the latter should be written

$$f( \, (x,y) \, )$$

just like a function that takes a single variable that is an angle is written as

$$f(\theta)$$

But nobody wants to write double parentheses all the time, and there is an obvious equivalence between functions of two variables and functions on $\mathbb R^2$, so people use the single-set-of-parentheses version all the time

And, as @aschepler notes in their comment, sometimes people get really lazy, and may write the application of a linear map to a vector as just "$Tv$", where they consider $T$ to be the $2\times 2$ matrix representing the map, $v$ to be the column vector (or $2 \times 1$ matrix) representing your vector, and putting them side-by-side indicates (matrix) multiplication, just like "$xy$" represents (regular) multiplication of two numbers.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on how the operation is defined. A vector space is just a contruction that satisfies certain rules, if that scalar multiplications works, it can be used.

Normally, the scalar multiplications defined on $\mathbb{R}^2$ is like you say, but there are others that works, the important thing is to have defined the operation before.

If your problem is interpretation, you can interpret geometrically as you say.(But check that the scalar multiplication you use is the one that has been defined).